# Objc ivar declaration location

Tags: objective-c

What is the difference between:

```
@interface MyClass 
{ 
    NSString *string; 
}
```

and...

```
NSString *string; 
@interface MyClass 
{ 
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one of these declarations declares an ivar: the first declaration makes an instance variable `string`, while the second declaration makes a global variable `string`. The ivar from the first declaration can be used only in instance methods, not in class methods. The global variable from the second declaration can be used in class methods as well as in instance methods, but all instance methods would share the same value of the `string` variable.

Comment: What happens if the second declaration is: extern NSString *string  ?

Comment: @individual11 Then it becomes a forward declaration of a global variable, meaning that you would need to put `NSString *string` in one of your .m files before you could use your `string`. If you put the second declaration in a header file, the version with `extern` is the correct one.